# Stopping applications in Mule Anypoint studio

Tags: mule

As per the link, Mule Anypoint Studio application launcher now supports launching multiple applications and it works. I could not find how to stop individual application if multiple are deployed?

http://blogs.mulesoft.org/release-studio-2015-01/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Studio's console refers to the JVM instance running the attached Mule distribution, not to each individual deployed app on that instance. However, if you modify any app config file, that app will be redeployed.
On the other hand, reviewing the log you can see that each app is deployed independently from `<workspace>/.mule/apps/<app-name>.zip`. After its deployment, a file named `<workspace>/.mule/apps/<app-name>-anchor.txt` will be created, if you remove that file the app will be undeployed.
HTH, Marcos.

Answer (score 0):

I did stop an individual app while others are still running. Please see the image below for your reference.

[image]

you can see the app mule-smtp has been stopped while others are in still running state.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score -2):

you can enable the mule run time in preferences tab of anypoint studio.

That is easiest way to stop specific applications on anypoint studio